# Multiple constructors in VB6?

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

Is it possible to have multiple constructors in vb6?  The reason I'm asking is because I see the class initialize, but i don't know if I can stick in 0 or more parameters into a constructor or if class_initialize is the constructor and it can accept any number of parameters.  Its confusing mainly because I am so familiar with c#, that going to vb6 is confounding as far as classes are concerned.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Class_Initialize` is an event that gets always gets invoked as soon as an instance of the class is instantiated. It's not really comparable to a C# constructor.

For example, notice the `Class_Initialize` is created as `Private`, whereas a C# class with a private constructor cannot be instantiated.

While you can change a VB6 `Class_Initialize` event from `Private` to `Public` there wouldn't be much point: because the event is invoked on instantiation anyway, why would you want to call it explicitly a second time? (If you did, it would be better to have a public method that is called from the `Class_Initialize` event.)

You cannot add parameters to VB6 `Class_Initialize` event, not even `Optional` ones. Attempting to do so will cause a compile error.

The best you can do is to roll your own `Initialize` method, with parameter as required, which must be explicitly called, perhaps and have an internal flag `isInitialized` state variable to ensure the class is not used until the `Initialize` method has been invoked. Also consider a 'factory' approach: classes that are `PublicNotCreatable` with `Friend Initialize` methods invoked by the factory and served out to callers suitable initialized.

Answer (score 2):

In VB6 you can specify method parameters as being `optional`. This means that you don't have to specify them when calling a function. In the case that they are not specified, a default value is given in the method signature.

An example from [here](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_optional_parameters.html):

```
Private Sub Draw(Optional X As Single = 720, Optional Y As Single = 2880)
    Cls
    Circle (X, Y), 700
End Sub
```

This can be called either:

```
Draw 'OR
Draw 100 'OR
Draw 200, 200
```

**Edit**
You can even use optional and regular parameters together, though I think you might have to put the optional ones at the end.

Comment: But you can't create a *constructor* with any arguments at all, optional or compulsory.

Comment: @MarkJ - Ah, you're right. I didn't realize this. I didn't use classes in VB6 very often and so never came across this issue. It says [here](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=313295) that the constructor is more like an event rather than a typical method. @Marc Noon: you should use onedaywhen's answer below. I will keep my answer here for reference on how to add the optional parameters to the custom `Initialize` method.